# Migrate Salesforce data from one org to another

Tags: salesforce, data-migration, salesforce-lightning

What are the freely available tools to clone **data** from one salesforce sandbox to another with minimal mapping work ?

Answer (score 1):

Are the objects, fields, and relationships in the new org?

If not, I would use the Ant Migration Tool or Eclipse to copy the metadata exactly from one org to the other.

Then, you can export the data from a report to Excel. With all field names matching precisely, Data Loader will automatically map the field names in Excel to the fields in Salesforce.

You will need to replace any ID values with valid IDs from the new org before you can successfully import the data *i.e. OwnerId, ParentId, etc*. Vlookups will do the heavy lifting in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

If you have records that are related to each other, you will need to create External Id fields on your sObjects to store their IDs in sandbox 1.  Here are the steps, using Accounts and Contacts as an example.

1. In Sandbox 2, Create a new field on Accounts called SandboxId, Text 18 UniqueCaseSensitive ExternalId
2. Extract Accounts using the Salesforce DataLoader from Sandbox 1.
3. Insert Accounts using the Salesforce DataLoader into Sandbox 2, mapping the Id column into the new SandboxId field.
4. Extract Contacts using the Salesforce DataLoader from Sandbox 1.
5. Upsert Contacts using the Salesforce DataLoader into Sandbox 2, specifying the SandboxId field as the External Id to match on for Account, and then set the mapping for the Account.SandboxId__c field to the AccountId column in the extract.

It gets tricky when you have circular relationships, but otherwise this technique works.